# Moving a UITabBar to the bottom

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tvos

Is there a way to move a tab bar from the top to the bottom on tvOS?
I want to create a custom one, but on the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried the "frame" property of the UITabBar ?

Comment: I've tried it, nothing changed. I expected it to change in the storyboard, I didn't actually built the app every time I changed something there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible using a `UITabBarController`. You can achieve this by adding a `UITabBar` to a `UIViewController` though. Example:

[image: UITabBar on bottom of view]

Comment: Thank you, got it working. Now I have to search how to get the tab buttons to work as they should

Comment: Do you happen to know how to proceed with this? I can't seem to find a way to add the logic to change views when the user selects a tabbaritem

Comment: @MihaiBlaga You're probably going to need to do most of the action handling and segues programmatically. Post a new question and I'll take a look and see if I can assist.

Comment: Got it working with buttons in the end, because for some reason (my best guess is that something overlapped) the tabbar was not receiving focus events. Thanks

Comment: @MihaiBlaga, can you please explain how you got it working ?

Comment: created a view on the bottom, with a few buttons in it and I used didUpdateFocusInContext to catch the focus events. Based on the focused button I change what's displayed in the content view